# Incorporate server socket into an html using Node.js / javascript

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, sockets

I am new to Node.js and javascript, hence don't have much experience and in need of some help.

I have a script that opens a simple server socket and just listens to incoming connection and prints the incoming message to the screen:

```
var net = require('net');

var server = net.createServer();  
server.on('connection', handleConnection);

server.listen(9000, function() {  
    console.log('server listening to %j', server.address());
});

function handleConnection(conn) {  
  var remoteAddress = conn.remoteAddress + ':' + conn.remotePort;
  console.log('new client connection from %s', remoteAddress);

  conn.on('data', onConnData);
  conn.once('close', onConnClose);
  conn.on('error', onConnError);

  function onConnData(d) {
      var chunks = [];
      chunks.push(d);
      console.log('Client at  %s  says %s', remoteAddress, Buffer.concat(chunks).toString());
    conn.write(d);
  }

  function onConnClose() {
    console.log('connection from %s closed', remoteAddress);
  }

  function onConnError(err) {
    console.log('Connection %s error: %s', remoteAddress, err.message);
  }
}
```

I have tested it and it works when i run it from the IDE (eclipse).
What I am trying to do is to incorporate this code inside an HTML file.
The HTML file does not suppose to be accessed from the out side, its for learning purposes only. 
Basically i would like to open the HTML file, it should run the code in the background (listen to the socket) and once the is a connection and data coming in it should print it on the screen (sing alert for example).
The HTML code looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <title>some title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script
        type = "text/javascript" src = "simple_server.js">
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

While trying to open the HTML file using a browser or inside eclipse it does nothing.
My question is, is it even possible? If it is, what am i doing wrong and how may I fix it?
Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: The web page needs its own JavaScript to communicate with the server that runs on port 9000. There is no point in loading the server JavaScript on the client. If you look in the developer console of your web browser there are probably a lot of error messages. You need to figure out the difference between the client (web browser) and the server (your Node.js application), and what code runs where. You almost never share code between client and server.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Did some reading after posting this question and got the same idea. Thanx again.